# Magento:: How filter by color attribute for configurable product in magento

Tags: magento

I am using the below code for filtering by color attributes but its giving empty array

```
$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->getCollection()
                                                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                                        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('color', 146);
```

Please advise  me

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 100% correct and I feel there's some other issue, Please check other part. If you are just fetching the product without category than remove this line

```
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
```